# Incorrect GROUP by function due to CONCAT

Tags: mysql

I am using `SUM()` to count lines with multiple conditions in the following manner

```
SELECT date(time),
SUM(CASE WHEN crit1 = 1 AND crit2 NOT LIKE CONCAT('%',table1.id,'%') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM table1, table2
GROUP BY date(time)
```

However what I noticed is that # of items that are counted is a multiple of items in the `table1`. So if there are 100 items that meet `crit1` and `crit2` criteria, and there are 5 items in `table1`, it would give me 500 items summed.
I added and removed items from table1 and it proportionally affected the SUM clause, to verify this.

How can it be summed without double counting for every case in CONCAT, or maybe a better way of counting all together?

Data structure:

```
table1          table2

id    name      time                  crit1   crit2 
123   A         2013-05-15 05:00:00     1     456
234   B         2013-05-15 05:00:00     2     789
345   C         2013-05-15 05:00:00     1     678
```

Note: IDs are unique

Desired output:

```
2013-05-15   2
```

Comment: Show your table(s) schema, sample data, and desired output based on it.

Comment: Could you post the entire query? If not, please post at least the `FROM` and `JOIN` parts. Based on the information given so far this could be a join problem.

Comment: there is actually no `JOIN`

Comment: Why is `time` not a `datetime` or `date` datatype? I think you should update your scheme.

Comment: this is very basic sample, `datetime` is used for other things

Comment: You are taking the cross product of two tables. The cross product has 500 rows which meet the criterion.

Comment: @Paulpro precisely, how can that be avoided? that item is counted once

Comment: Can you explain how these two tables are related?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You don't have any foreign key relating your tables, so there is no way to know which criteria to compare each row from `table1` to. Right now you compare each row with every criteria, which is fine to do without a foreign key, but if you want a more specific relation, then you need a foreign key or another table which serves the purpose of relating these two.

Comment: If you want a one-to-one relationship, I would recommend adding a column to `table2` called `table1` (whatever your table is actually named) which correlates to the `id` you want that entry to correspond to from table1.

Comment: crit2 and id are related, i just made 3 lines for example. There are items in crit2 and id which are equal, hence it needs to check that crit2 is not part of ids

Comment: Are you trying to count the number of times where `crit1 = 1` and `crit2` is not anywhere in table1?

Comment: If `id = 32`  and `crit2 = 320` do you want that to count or do you want to exclude it, since the string id is a substring of `crit2`?

Comment: exclude, it has to be identical match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want this:

```
SELECT date(time), COUNT(crit2)
FROM table2 
WHERE 
     table2.crit1 = 1
  AND
     table2.crit2 NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table1)
GROUP BY date(time)
```

Comment: Let me know if that works correctly for what you need and if not and I'm still awake I'll try to update it.

Comment: Cannt I use `NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table1)` inside of SUM()?

Comment: @rodling Yes, you can also do it that way, just make sure that you also then remove that cross product. Change `FROM table1, table2` to just `FROM table2`, otherwise you'll still get the extra results.

Comment: giving me syntax error hmm, also this might be a problem because I want to put this into a view

Comment: @rodling What's the syntax error? It works here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e781/31/0 (This is gillyspy's SQL Fiddle edited with a new query)